# Can we make localhost inside native iOS app

Tags: ios, swift, uiwebview

I have to load a html file using http protocol in UIWebView or WKWebView. Here is my code using WKWebView:

```
import UIKit
import WebKit

class ViewController: UIViewController,WKUIDelegate {

    var webView: WKWebView!

    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()
        // Do any additional setup after loading the view, typically from a nib.

        let webConfiguration = WKWebViewConfiguration()
        webView = WKWebView(frame: self.view.frame, configuration: webConfiguration)
        webView.uiDelegate = self

        let path = URL(fileURLWithPath: "index.html")
        let myURL = path
        let myRequest = URLRequest(url: myURL)
        webView.load(myRequest)
        self.view.addSubview(webView)
    }

    override func didReceiveMemoryWarning() {
        super.didReceiveMemoryWarning()
        // Dispose of any resources that can be recreated.
    }
}
```

Is it possible to resolve http protocal from native bundle?

Answer (score 0):

Yes, it's possible. You need to run HTTP server in your application to achieve that. Personally, I would recommend using [GCDWebServer](https://github.com/swisspol/GCDWebServer).

Comment: Thanks @Boris. My requirement is I have a folder inside my native app namely www and it has an index.html file to run. The index.html file internally calls REST calls using ajax. I want the index.html should be served using http protocol not file protocol. I have seen the GCDWebServer which opens a port in my mac which I don't need. Hope now its clear to you. Thanks for your reply.